# Best way to count millions of rows between certain dates in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, performance

Here is my SQL for creating a table:

```
$sql_create_table = "CREATE TABLE {$table_name} (
                  hit_id bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
                  user_id int(7) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
                  optin_id int(8) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
                  hit_date datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
                  hit_type varchar(10) NOT NULL default '',
                  PRIMARY KEY  (hit_id),
                  KEY user_id (user_id)
             ) $charset_collate; ";
```

I need to know the fastest way to count the number of rows within a query. My current query doesn't cut it for going through millions of rows.

```
$sql = "SELECT hit_id FROM $table_name WHERE user_id = %d AND hit_type = %s AND hit_date >= FROM_UNIXTIME(%d) AND hit_date <= FROM_UNIXTIME(%d)";
```

I've tried this with no luck (not returning the proper results):

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $table_name WHERE user_id = %d AND hit_type = %s AND hit_date >= FROM_UNIXTIME(%d) AND hit_date <= FROM_UNIXTIME(%d)";
```

What do I need to do to make this query efficient so that it doesnt time out for millions of rows? I simply want to count the number of rows within the specified parameter set.

Comment: does the table have a clustered index? Any indexes?

Comment: You need to put an index on the column that you're searching the range on.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of the performance of the FROM_UNIXTIME function, but the first thing I would do is create an index on hit_date.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html

Comment: And on user_id and on hit_type. (Rule of thumb: index everything that's used in a WHERE clause.)

Comment: I'm not familiar with indexes. Could you provide me with an example?